# Replacing cord for IBM model M keyboard

Tags: keyboards, ibm, maintenance

I bought a model m keyboard for use at work. The keyboard functions fine, but the cord is in bad shape. Functionally, the cord does not cause any shorts, but the plastic is very brittle and large chunks of it have fallen off.

This is a 1994 model m (Part Number 71G4644) with the attached PS/2 cable. I want to replace the cable with a new one, preferably like the classic, coiled cords. My question is where I can find a replacement cord?

Comment: This question might not be a good fit for the site, as it seems like a shopping recommendation question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 You may be correct, but I was angling for an answer from someone who has restored one of these keyboards. This site seemed to be the best choice to find someone with that sort of experience.

Answer (score 5):

Replacement cables are available from Unicomp (https://www.pckeyboard.com/) but you might not be able to get a coiled cord in the 'permanently attached' variant.  They do appear to have coiled cords of the 'detachable' type, but you would need the corresponding socket on your keyboard (it looks vaguely like an RJ45 connector, but with plastic tangs on both sides rather than the top).

Unicomp also sells 'modern' Model M variants (with USB interface and Windows keys) if you're interested.

Comment: The modern Unicomps feel and behave just like the classic IBM keyboards. Buying one is the low-hassle solution.

Comment: That could be a possibility, to instead replace the attached cord with a detachable cord, granted I can get a jack.

Answer (score 3):

This is not your typical model M! I can see why you like it. :)

Honestly, a donated ps/2 cable from another keyboard would work the best. They usually have stress relief blocks molded on, and it should not be hard to make a slightly larger one fit with a sharp knife. Then just crimp or solder the new wire to your keyboard mainboard, and shinkwrap the connections. Make sure the stress relief is working and not pulling on the wires.